# trying to implement APP_UNINSTALLED webhook using Shopify Cli 3 new template

Tags: node.js, shopify

I am trying to create an APP_UNINSTALLED webhook using new cli3 node template, but i am not getting it, anyone here implemented the webhook ? If you can guide me or share a piece of code it will be life saving. Thank you all.

I tried to add it on gdpr.js but i am not getting it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can add and handle the webhook using the shopify API `addHandlers` method.
For example, using `node.js`, you can create this:

```
webhooks/app-uninstall.js

import { DeliveryMethod } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
// Configured from the shopify app node.js boilerplate
import shopify from "../shopify";

async function addUninstallWebhookHandler() {
  return await shopify.api.webhooks.addHandlers({
    APP_UNINSTALLED: {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks/app-uninstall",
      callback: async (topic, shop) => {
        console.log("Uninstall app webhook invoked", topic, shop);
        // Invoke analytics, database query etc.
      },
    },
  });
}
export default addUninstallWebhookHandler;
```

Call this function in your express app

To test this webhook please trigger this command `npm run shopify webhook trigger` and select app/uninstalled

Comment: What if I need to make a web request using the app I have defined in index.js? How can I access that client within this webhook handler?